# How to programmatically know who (other java files/classes) is using my java class?

Tags: java

I want to get a list of all java class which are dependent on my class. Is there a library which exposes intended API? API is expected to return list of java classes using my java class.

Comment: Clarification needed.
1st runtime dependent or compile time dependent
2nd, define dependent. must A have a direct field accessing B to be dependent, or would chaining count.
for example would
person.getName().trim()
constitute a dependency on string?

Comment: 1st compile time dependent 2nd define dependent. What i am looking for which all java classes use/extend my class.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably use [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)..

They were specifically made for this kind of problems..  They allow to get information about classes at runtime..
You can get: -

- All the methods
- All the derived classes
- All the variables.
- And many more information..

You can see [Class.getClasses()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses%28%29) and [Class.getDeclaredClasses()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses%28%29)

See [some more examples](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can tell you whether a specific class extends your class, uses your class as a field, takes your class as a parameter, or returns your class from a method. However if the use of your class is method confined then reflection will not work.